# How to correctly code max, min, and avg in this code?

Tags: java, if-statement, null

I cannot figure out why my code is:

1. giving me a null output
2. not calculating the max, min values, and average values.

There are two classes in my code, and I'm supposed to find the average, max, and min of a set of values.

```java
public class CirclesV8
    {
    //declaration of private instance variables
    private double myRadius, mySphere; 
    private double myArea = 0, total = 0; 

    //instance variables for totals average 
    private double MyTotal = 0; 
    private double MyAverage = 0;

    //constructor for objects of type CirclesV8
    public CirclesV8(int r, int s)
    {
        myRadius = r;
        mySphere = s; 
        MyTotal = total;
    } 

    //getter method for radius and total
    public double getRadius()
    {
        return myRadius; 
    }

    public double getSphere()
    {
        return mySphere; 
    }

    public double getTotal()
    {
        return MyTotal;
    }

    //mutator method for the area, average, and circumference
    public void calcArea()
    {
        myArea = Math.PI * (Math.pow(myRadius, 2)); 
    }
    public double getArea()
    {
        return myArea; 
    }

    public void calcSurfaceArea()
    {
        mySphere = (Math.pow(myRadius, 2)) * Math.PI * 4; 
    }
    public double getSurfaceArea()
    {
        return mySphere;
    }

    public void calcAvg()
    {
        MyAverage = MyTotal / 5; 
    }

    public double getAvg()
    {
        return MyAverage; 
    }

    //setter method for myTotal
    public void setTotal(double total)
    {
        MyTotal = total;
    }

    // returns a String of the object's values. The format() method is similar to printf().
    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%12d %14.1f %13.1f 12.1f", myRadius,
                                                         myArea,
                                                         mySphere,
                                                         MyAverage);
    }
    }

    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class V8Tester
    {
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //create scanner object 
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);               

        //initialize variables 
        int radius1, radius2, radius3, radius4, radius5; 
        int sphere1, sphere2, sphere3, sphere4, sphere5; 
        double Average = 0;
        double total = 0; 
        double min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        double max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;


        System.out.println("Please enter five radiuses separate by space (ex. 6 12)"); 
        radius1 = in.nextInt();
        radius2 = in.nextInt();
        radius3 = in.nextInt(); 
        radius4 = in.nextInt();
        radius5 = in.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter another 5 radiuses separate by space (ex. 6 12)"); 
        sphere1 = in.nextInt();
        sphere2 = in.nextInt();
        sphere3 = in.nextInt(); 
        sphere4 = in.nextInt();
        sphere5 = in.nextInt(); 

        //Create array of objects                         
        CirclesV8 [] circles = {new CirclesV8(radius1, sphere1), 
                                new CirclesV8(radius2, sphere2),
                                new CirclesV8(radius3, sphere3),
                                new CirclesV8(radius4, sphere4),
                                new CirclesV8(radius5, sphere5)}; 

       //call methods                 
        for(int index = 0; index < circles.length; index++)
        {
            circles[index].calcArea();
            circles[index].calcSurfaceArea();
            circles[index].calcAvg(); 

            //store totals for calculating average 
            total += circles[index].getTotal();

            //calc max and min
            if(circles[index].getTotal() < min)
                  min = circles[index].getTotal();
            if(circles[index].getTotal() > max)
                  max = circles[index].getTotal();
        }

        //set total values & call average methods to calculate averages using one of the objects
        circles[4].setTotal(total); 
        circles[4].calcArea();
        circles[4].calcSurfaceArea(); 
        circles[4].getAvg();

        //Circle Colors
        System.out.println("Color of Circle #1: ");
        String circle1 = in.next(); 

        System.out.println("Color of Circle #2: ");
        String circle2 = in.next();

        System.out.println("Color of Circle #3: ");
        String circle3 = in.next(); 

        System.out.println("Color of Circle #4: ");
        String circle4 = in.next();

        System.out.println("Color of Circle #5: ");
        String circle55 = in.next();

        String[] array = new String[5];
        array[0] = circle1;
        array[1] = circle2; 
        array[2] = circle3;
        array[3] = circle4;
        array[4] = circle55;

        //Sphere Colors
        System.out.println("Color of Sphere #1: ");
        String sphere11 = in.next(); 

        System.out.println("Color of Sphere #2: ");
        String sphere22 = in.next();

        System.out.println("Color of Sphere #3: ");
        String sphere33 = in.next(); 

        System.out.println("Color of Sphere #4: ");
        String sphere44 = in.next();

        System.out.println("Color of Sphere #5: ");
        String sphere55 = in.next();

        String[] arr = new String[5];
        array[0] = sphere11;
        array[1] = sphere22; 
        array[2] = sphere33;
        array[3] = sphere44;
        array[4] = sphere55;

        int i = 1;
        System.out.println(" Color     Radius       Surface Area       Area");
        System.out.println("==============================================================");
        for(int index = 0; index < circles.length; index++)
        {            
            System.out.printf("%4s %10.1f %14.1f%n", array[index],
                                                     circles[index].getRadius(),
                                                     circles[index].getArea(),
                                                     i++); 
        }
```

```java
    public class CirclesV8
    {
        //declaration of private instance variables
        private double myRadius, mySphere; 
        private double myArea = 0, total = 0; 

        //instance variables for totals average 
        private double MyTotal = 0; 
        private double MyAverage = 0;

        //constructor for objects of type CirclesV8
        public CirclesV8(int r, int s)
        {
            myRadius = r;
            mySphere = s; 
            MyTotal = total;
        } 

        //getter method for radius and total
        public double getRadius()
        {
            return myRadius; 
        }

        public double getSphere()
        {
            return mySphere; 
        }

        public double getTotal()
        {
            return MyTotal;
        }

        //mutator method for area, average, and circumference
        public void calcArea()
        {
            myArea = Math.PI * (Math.pow(myRadius, 2)); 
        }
        public double getArea()
        {
            return myArea; 
        }

        public void calcSurfaceArea()
        {
            mySphere = (Math.pow(myRadius, 2)) * Math.PI * 4; 
        }
        public double getSurfaceArea()
        {
            return mySphere;
        }

        public void calcAvg()
        {
            MyAverage = MyTotal / 5; 
        }

        public double getAvg()
        {
            return MyAverage; 
        }

        //setter method for myTotal
        public void setTotal(double total)
        {
            MyTotal = total;
        }

        // returns a String of the object's values. The format() method is similar to printf().
        public String toString()
        {
            return String.format("%12d %14.1f %13.1f 12.1f", myRadius,
                                                             myArea,
                                                             mySphere,
                                                             MyAverage);
        }
    }
```

This gives me a null output

```
        for(int index = 0; index < circles.length; index++)
        {            
            System.out.printf("%4s %10.1f %20f", arr[index],
                                                 circles[index].getRadius(),
                                                 circles[index].getSurfaceArea(),
                                                 i++); 
        }
        System.out.println("==============================================================");
```

I can't get this to print values

```
        System.out.printf("%20s%n", "Minimum: ", max); 
        System.out.printf("%20s%n", "Maximum: ", min); 
        System.out.printf("%20s%n", "Average: ", circles[4].getAvg()); 
       }
       }
```

Comment: Please add the tag of the programming language. Also, check why running the snippet is giving a syntax error.

Comment: Your **String.format()** and **System.out.printf()** calls are wrong. Step back and create your code to handle only circles (not spheres as well). Get that working first. What exactly is **min**, **max**, and **avg** for? What is the purpose of these particular variables? These variables may need to be static. Check where you fill arrays. There is a point where you overwrite the array[] array. This is wrong. You want to fill the arr[] array. etc, etc.

Comment: This is java code. Instructions: Add any instance variables, constructors, or methods needed to the object implementation class. Include getter and setter methods for each instance value. Include toString() method that'll return a String representing the values of a given instance of the object.

Comment: This project should have no fewer than five instances of your object. Your program design needs be based on an array of objects. Determine minimum and maximum values key data columns. Calculate average for key data columns.